# LiveAgent.startChat(): wrong redirecting

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat, startchat

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false"  cache="true" > 

<head> Redirecting to the Liveagent chat Page </head>

<div id="liveagent_invite_button_5732500000XXXXX" style='margin:0px; padding: 0px; width:400px; border-radius:8px; display: none;' >
<!-- DEPLOYMENT -->

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c1cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/34.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script>

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // In this part I insert informations that I will need when I will 
    // open the chat with the Agent.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    liveagent.addCustomDetail("IdAOL", new Date().getTime());
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Info__c").map("ID_AOL__c", "IdAOL", false, false,true);
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Info__c").showOnCreate();
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Info__c").saveToTranscript("Info__c","Info__c");
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Survey_Operatore__c").map("ID_AOL__c", "IdAOL", false, false,true);
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Survey_Operatore__c").showOnCreate();
    liveagent.findOrCreate("Survey_Operatore__c").saveToTranscript("Survey_Operatore__c","Survey_Operatore__c");
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c1cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5722500000XXXXX', '00D25000000XXXX');
    //----------------------------------------------
    // start of the chat giving us the problem!!!
    liveagent.startChat('5732500000XXXXX', true); 

</script>

// URL-hacking I am NOT using anymore
// <body onload="window.location.href = 'https://1c3.la1-c1cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/s/chat?language=it#deployment_id=57225000000XXXX&org_id=00D25000000XXXX&button_id=5732500000XXXXX';">
</body>

<!-- FINE DEPLOYMENT -->
</div>

</apex:page>
```

XXX nb= I don't want solve through URL-hacking. XXX

The page redirects to a PreChat that is NOT on the invitation. I think it could be a Salesforce issue, but I cannot find it on the web.
[image]

Comment: Honestly: URL-hacking is called like that because it is exactly that. That also means that it may break or no longer be supported at any given time. I would not build new functionality using this.

Comment: I have tried to use the simple StartChat(invitation_Id) but it redirects me on a Pre-Chat Page with address "null" (instead of going directly on the chat without a Pre-Chat page as it happens when you use the same code on a button). If I'll find a solution I'll be happy to use it without hacking anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end we have opened a case to Salesforce and there was a solution not yet documented by Salesforce (but I think they will do it as soon as possible).

It is necessary to change the liveagent.startchat() with the following timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
        liveagent.startChatWithWindow('573250000008OLT', 'window'); 
    },2000);
```